Fetching nexted yaml file data in python
I need to loop through the main tag and fetch its subtag value in python scrip.
Sorry i am recently started using python script.

Yaml file:-

Chart1: 
    Slide: 1
    Top: 100
    Left: 100
    Width: 150
    Heigth: 150
Chart2: 
    Slide: 1
    Top: 100
    Left: 100
    Width: 150
    Heigth: 150
Chart3: 
    Slide: 1
    Top: 100
    Left: 100
    Width: 150
    Heigth: 150

import yaml 
from munch import Munch
#Read Yaml file

with open(r"C:\Users\ana\Chart\config.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    data_loaded = yaml.safe_load(stream)
configyaml = Munch(data_loaded)
print(data_loaded)
for index in range(3):
        Slidenumber = configyaml.Chart + index +.Slide
        STop = configyaml.Chart + index +.Top
        Sleft= configyaml.Chart + index +.Left
        print(Slidenumber)
        print(STop)
        print(Sleft)


What is Munch? Your initial data_loaded is a dict like {'Chart1': {'Slide': 1, 'Top': 100, ...}, 'Chart2': {...}, 'Chart3': {...}}.

If you use the dict by itself, something like for chart in data_loaded: for key in chart: print(chart[key]).

By using this index variable how can i call each chart1,chart2 to chartn
'for index, xlChart in enumerate(xlCharts):'
'Slidenumber = data_loaded['Chart' + index].key['Slide']'

Having looked at munch, I think this is just making your job harder. Just use the dict that yaml.safe_load returns. (Really, just don't bother with the attribute access provided by munch, but that seems to be the only reason to bother using munch at all.)

You don't have any tags in the YAML document you show. Tags in YAML, start with an exclamation mark (!).

You are trying to read a yaml file contaning three charts, and then loop through each chart to fetch specific values and print them out. However, there are a few issues in your code that are preventing the values from being displayed correctly.

When using Munch library, you should access attributes with data.attribute instead of .attribute.
The keys of the charts in your dictionary are strings (Chart1, Chart2, Chart3). To access them correctly, you must dynamically construct them using formatted strings: f"Chart{index}".
The loop range must be adjusted to start from 1 and go up to 3. Using range(3) starts the loop from 0 to 2, which does not align with the required keys.

    for index in range(1, 4):
        chart_data = configyaml.get(f"Chart{index}")
        if chart_data:
            Slidenumber = char_data.get('Slide')
            STop = chart_data.get('Top')
            SLeft = chart_data.get('Left')
            print(f"Chart {index}: Slide={Slidenumber}, Top={STop}, Left={Sleft}")

With these modifications, the code should work correctly, allowing you to loop through each chart, retrieve the desired values, and print them as intended.
